# Heroku app buildpack fails after compiling successfully

Tags: c, heroku, makefile, installation, buildpack

I'm trying to build a `C` application using a custom heroku buildpack specifically for it. The problem is that after compiling it gets to the very last stage `-----> Installing` and fails. Would someone be able to explain what I need to do in order to successfully deploy it?

Commands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/znc/znc.git && cd znc
$ heroku create --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/lonnen/heroku-buildpack-znc.git

Creating dark-clouds-666... 
done, stack is cedar
BUILDPACK_URL=http://github.com/lonnen/heroku-buildpack-znc.git
http://dark-clouds-666.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:dark-clouds-666.git
Git remote heroku added

$ git push heroku master
```

... then it goes on to build everything seemingly normal ...

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> C app detected
-----> Running autogen.sh
-----> Configuring
-----> Compiling with Make

       Linking znc...

       ZNC was successfully compiled.
       Use 'make install' to install ZNC to '/usr/local'.

-----> Installing
       test -d /usr/local/bin || /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/bin
       test -d /usr/local/include/znc || /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/include/znc
/usr/bin/install: cannot change permissions of `/usr/local/include/znc': No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile C app

To git@heroku.com:dark-clouds-666.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:dark-clouds-666.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user does not have permission to write in `/usr/local`. Usually, `make install` is done by root user, where `make` could be done by normal users.

The fastest way is to execute all by root user, which is unsafe, as you can modify everything, leading to a broken system.

You can set an install location different from `/usr/local`, or you can force heroku to ask for root permission (`sudo make install`).